# Extract textual data from a PDF

Tags: java, pdf

I'm using a Java program to extract textual data from a PDF.

When I use this type of PDF I have no problem :

[image]

But when I use this type the extraction is not performed :

[image]

Have you any idea to resolve this problem?

Comment: Both pictures are exactly same. What you want to show?

Comment: These are two identical images.

Comment: i thing no signature is a problem. PDF can be from two sources: ffrom software, build in 'vector' philosophy, and envelope for bitmaps from scanners

Comment: Sorry I update the second picture

Comment: The first "type of pdf" contains a form definition, the second does not. Probably your java program only extracts form contents? (As you neither share your pivotal code nor example PDFs, only wild speculation is possible in response to your question...)

Comment: Show us your source code. Tell us which "Java program" you are using.

Answer (score 1):

Try using iText7 and following code:

```
File inputFile = new File("path_to_your_pdf");
PdfDocument pdfDocument = new PdfDocument(new PdfReader(inputFile));
String text = PdfTextExtractor.getTextFromPage(pdfDocument.getPage(1));
pdfDocument.close();
```

And let us know what the output is. And whether the output corresponds to what you'd expect.

As @mkl points out, this may simply be the the difference between extracting form-fields or not. In any case, the links to your pdfs would be much appreciated. As well as some code.

But you can of course extract both using iText.

Reading material:

- http://developers.itextpdf.com/content/itext-7-examples/itext-7-form-examples
- http://developers.itextpdf.com/content/itext-7-examples/itext-7-content-extraction-and-redaction